# Python not printing everything

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I love you all. First time with Python, I am reading in a csv with 10842 cities and counting how many occurrences there are of each. When I print to terminal it outputs the first 29 cities, prints ... and then prints 10813 - 10842. This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Csz.csv')
s = df['City'].value_counts().rename('Total_City')
df = df.join(s, on='City')

print (df)
```

I'm a bit lost on how to get all of them to print, and hopefully after will figure out how to remove duplicates. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're using pandas, the default is to truncate long dataframes. You should probably look for a better way than printing it all out to find duplicates...

Comment: You need a [MCVE] here; some smaller set of inputs that trigger the problem, along with the actual and expected outputs make diagnosing your problem much easier.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your code right after the imports

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 999
```

see the doc for full explanation:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html